# Migrating to mySQL5 supported server - does it take a day?

Tags: mysql, migrating

Am helping someone to install WP on their current host, which unfortunately only has mySQL4 (whereas WP now requires mySQL5)  and their host responded with this message:

> "can host it somewhere else that has mysql5 but you will need to
>   reconfigure domains and setup all e-mails!!!!!!!  *snip*  I can transfer the setup to the new one, do not forget you have 3 domains with probably more than 20 email addresses on each, this is a day work!"

I don't know anything about migrating servers, but I assume the main issue is with email downtime whilst the domain is propogating... but will it really be day's work transferring email accounts etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your setup but if the implication is that server IPs will change, then the requisite changes to DNS records could take 24-48 hours to propagate. The actual migration of a WP blog and its data is fairly trivial and shouldn't take more than a couple of hours. Overall turnaround time will obviously depend on your host's workload.

There's still no reason why you can't keep the old server running during the transition to avoid any downtime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. It was very helpful! I shall feed this back to the person I'm helping.